# Django template context not working with imported class

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates

I'm using Django's templating on appengine, and am having a problem whereby a class I'm importing from another package is not correctly being made available to the template context. The context is set in the code, but is empty once rendered in the template.

Broadly speaking, this is the code. The prop1 is not available in the template in the first example below, but is in the second. MyClass is identical in both cases.

This does not work:

```
from module import MyClass
context = MyClass()
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, context))
```

This does:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = "prop1"

context = MyClass()
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, context))
```

If I log the context in the above code I get:

```
<module.MyClass object at 0x107b1e450>
```

when it's imported, and:

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x103759390>
```

when it's defined in the same file.

Any clues as to what might cause this kind of behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by not correctly made available?

Comment: The context is None, or at least renders as empty.

Comment: Could you add the part of your template code that is causing an issue?

Comment: Well, that would just be {{ prop1 }}. Nothing appears.

Comment: Did you try using the {% debug %} template tag (if it works on AppEngine - it does on Django) and see what comes up? However, do you have a specific reason for not using the usual dict as a context?

Comment: Yes - I could work around it I guess. But there's a bunch of useful things this class does, and then I just want to be able to throw it in to my template and access its properties. I guess I'm just confused about when and why a class would behave differently when it's imported from another package as opposed to being declared in the file. In fact, in my real example this class inherits from a superclass which is defined in the outside package, and that doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: As a workaround, you could probably pass the instance in the context dict instead of using it as a context itself.

Comment: Okay - I've no idea what stupid thing I was doing, but this is now working. Sorry to waste your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom context class it should extend Django's `BaseContext`. Otherwise it won't have the default behaviour of a regular context.

```
from django.template import BaseContext

class MyClass(BaseContext):
    # Your stuff here
    pass
```